# How to make simple SQL request in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me guys!

My code doesn't work :( 
Where is my error?

```
SELECT * from dummy_table where `a` + `b` + `c` like '99';
```

I have empty return although there are some rows where sum of (a,b,c) gives 99.

**a is integer while b,c are DOUBLE. Could this lead into an issue?**

Comment: I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If those are numeric columns it should be `= 99` not `LIKE '99'`

Comment: To compare numeric expression result, use `=` instead of `like`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a mathematical comparison in your WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM dummy_Table WHERE a + b + c = 99
```

If you are concerned that the double may contain a small precision that you want to disregard when comparing then round the columns with doubles to your preferred precision, for instance 2 decimals.

```
SELECT * FROM dummy_Table WHERE a + ROUND(b,2) + ROUND(c,2) = 99
```

Comment: PERFECT! IT WORKS! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to sum a,b,c as letters not as columns.
Try removing the single quotes.

Is '99' the full match? You could also try '%99%' if it makes sense in your case.

Comment: these things you call single quotes around the column names are not quotes but **backticks** which is something else in MySQL.

Comment: @Thalles Ribeiro  if I use such rule when I have many rows which are not distinct with my rule.